# Target index of array

Tags: php

I'm trying to target the index of my array. For some reason my array turns out really weird.

```php
        foreach ($name as $n) {
          for ($x = 0; $x < count($mednames); $x++) {
            if (in_array($n, $mednames[$x])) {
              $duplicaten[] = $n;
              break;
            }
          }
        }

        $cnt = array_count_values($duplicaten);

        foreach ($cnt as $c) {
          if ($cnt > 1) {
            echo '<h2 style="color: gray;">';
            print_r($c);
            echo '</h2>';
          }
        }
```

Now I get the results I need. But I need the name of each index too.

Results:

var export - $name:

```
array ( 
0 => 'Ibuprofen', 
1 => 'Ibuprofen', 
2 => 'Penicillin', 
3 => 'Penicillin', 
4 => 'Penicillin', 
5 => 'Adderall', 
)
```

var_export - $mednames:

```
array ( 
0 => array ( 'name' => 'xxxx1', 'med_name' => 'Ibuprofen', ), 
1 => array ( 'name' => 'xxxx2', 'med_name' => 'Ibuprofen', ), 
2 => array ( 'name' => 'xxxx3', 'med_name' => 'Penicillin', ), 
3 => array ( 'name' => 'xxxx4', 'med_name' => 'Penicillin', ), 
4 => array ( 'name' => 'xxxx5', 'med_name' => 'Penicillin', ), 
5 => array ( 'name' => 'xxxx6', 'med_name' => 'Adderall', ), 
)
```

var_export - $cnt:

```
array ( 'Ibuprofen' => 2, 'Penicillin' => 3, 'Adderall' => 1, )
```

var_export - $c:

```
2
3
```

Now the problem here is that I need to have the name of each medicine in the $c variable/array, because I need the name of the medicine to get more information from the api. But the problem is I'm only getting the count for it. Is there a workaround for this? This is really bugging me. I've been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: can you write what you exectly expect?

Comment: @MaikLowrey I basically expect the result I get the in the $cnt-array, but without the medicine that only occurs once. So I can use the names of the medicine to search.

Comment: what should the array look like at the end of the day? For example? `[ ibu => 2, para => 3, ...]`

Comment: What is the purpose of $name if it has the same med_name in the same order as  $mednames?

Comment: @MaikLowrey I'm sorry but I don't know how to explain it better, but in a normal array I can target a value by for example doing it this way: $cnt["med_name"] and $cnt["cnt"] to get the med name and count. So If would want to do a comparison I could use: if($cnt["cnt"] > 1) { blabla }. And that's how I want this array to be. I'm sorry if I'm unclear.

Comment: @lukas.j to search inside the database I need the "name" index. It is a code that the database uses as a key.

Comment: @leo I understand you need tha med_name as array key

Comment: @MaikLowrey yes and I need the count too. And it needs to be connected to the med_name. array ( 
0 => array ( 'med_name' => 'Ibuprofen', 'cnt' => '2', ). Something like that. Is that clearer?

Comment: Hi @leo, could you give us an example of what is the result that you expect?

Comment: @leo: I do not understand why $name and med_name within $med_names are exactly the same in the same order. Then you do not need $name.

Comment: @Edgar array ( 0 => array ( 'med_name' => 'Ibuprofen', 'cnt' => '2', ),  something like this. Just so I can target the medicine name and count.

Comment: @lukas.j Because I need the code that is connected to each medicine. And the code is the "name"-index. I don't know how to explain it further. But I do need it to be that way.

Comment: Ok, I understand, can you post a sample of how the initial array looks like?

Comment: @Edgar all arrays I'm using have been posted in the question.

Comment: @leo: Sorry, doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: @leo Ok, it's clear

Comment: Just to be sure, this is what you need:array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["med_name"]=>
    string(9) "Ibuprofen"
    ["cnt"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["med_name"]=>
    string(10) "Penicillin"
    ["cnt"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["med_name"]=>
    string(8) "Adderall"
    ["cnt"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}

Comment: @Edgar DigitalJedi's answer solved it. I just needed to get the $name variable that he suggests in his answer. That was what I was askinng for. Thanks alot for taking your time!

Comment: @leo, yes he beat me to it, I just saw his answer as I was posting mine. I'm glad you found a solution.

Comment: @Edgar haha I'm glad too. Been struggling for a good while and yet the solution was so simple... Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the key in the second foreach:

```
<?php

$name = array ( 
0 => 'Ibuprofen', 
1 => 'Ibuprofen', 
2 => 'Penicillin', 
3 => 'Penicillin', 
4 => 'Penicillin', 
5 => 'Adderall', 
);

$mednames = array ( 
0 => array ( 'name' => 'xxxx1', 'med_name' => 'Ibuprofen', ), 
1 => array ( 'name' => 'xxxx2', 'med_name' => 'Ibuprofen', ), 
2 => array ( 'name' => 'xxxx3', 'med_name' => 'Penicillin', ), 
3 => array ( 'name' => 'xxxx4', 'med_name' => 'Penicillin', ), 
4 => array ( 'name' => 'xxxx5', 'med_name' => 'Penicillin', ), 
5 => array ( 'name' => 'xxxx6', 'med_name' => 'Adderall', ), 
);


foreach ($name as $n) {
  for ($x = 0; $x < count($mednames); $x++) {
    if (in_array($n, $mednames[$x])) {
      $duplicaten[] = $n;
      break;
    }
  }
}

$cnt = array_count_values($duplicaten);

print_r($cnt);
/* prints
Array
(
    [Ibuprofen] => 2
    [Penicillin] => 3
    [Adderall] => 1
)
*/


// again do foreach with $key => $value
foreach ($cnt as $name =>  $c) {
  if ($cnt > 1) {
    echo '<h2 style="color: gray;">';
    print($c);
    print('-');
    print($name);
    echo '</h2>';
  }
}
/* prints:
    <h2 style="color: gray;">2-Ibuprofen</h2><h2 style="color: gray;">3-Penicillin</h2><h2 style="color: gray;">1-Adderall</h2>
*/
```

You can test this in php Sandbox, that this is in fact correct behaviour:

https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can itearate your result array again like this.

```
$m = array ( 
  array ( 'name' => 'xxxx1', 'med_name' => 'Ibuprofen', ), 
  array ( 'name' => 'xxxx2', 'med_name' => 'Ibuprofen', ), 
  array ( 'name' => 'xxxx5', 'med_name' => 'Ibuprofen', ), 
  array ( 'name' => 'xxxx3', 'med_name' => 'Penicillin', ), 
  );

$export = array ( 'Ibuprofen' => 2, 'Penicillin' => 3, 'Adderall' => 1, );
$newM = [];
foreach($m as $i) {
    if (! isset($newM[$i['med_name']])) {
        $_counting = 0; 
    }
    $_counting++;
    $newM[$i['med_name']] = $i;
    $newM[$i['med_name']]['count'] = $export[$i['med_name']];
    $newM[$i['med_name']]['counting'] = $_counting;
    
}

print_r($newM);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [Ibuprofen] => Array
        (
            [name] => xxxx5
            [med_name] => Ibuprofen
            [count] => 2
            [counting] => 3
        )

    [Penicillin] => Array
        (
            [name] => xxxx3
            [med_name] => Penicillin
            [count] => 3
            [counting] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, but this is not what my problem is. My $mednames array basically looks like this. What I'm having trouble with is after I do the count. The count is what I'm trying to achieve here. I need the medicine name and the amount of times the medicine occurs in the array. What I'm trying to achieve is based on the medicine name and the count.

Comment: @leo I  updated with count. I asume that this `array ( 'Ibuprofen' => 2, 'Penicillin' => 3, 'Adderall' => 1, )`is your stock?

Comment: Yeah I saw it now. I will try it. No basically I have an application where a patient can renew his/hers prescription. So the count is for how many prescriptions of the medicine a patient has left. When the prescription count is down to 1 the patient will be notified about it and be able to send a request to the hospital to renew it. That's what I need the count for. But I will try your solution. Thanks!

Comment: @leo i still don't think this is the solution. sorry.  :-/ I have now added a duplicate counter. counting.

Comment: thanks alot for your time. Unfortunately what you suggested didn't work. But DigitalJedi's answer did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can access array's key in the `foreach` as follows,

```
foreach ($cnt as $key => $c) {
    if ($cnt > 1) {
        echo '<h2 style="color: gray;">';
        echo $key;
        print_r($c);
        echo '</h2>';
    }
}
```

Read more about [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this. I get the same result. I'm not getting the name of the medicine, I'm just getting the count.

Comment: This should have printed the key. Could you please share your updated script?